# How can I override WRAPPER in a Template Toolkit template file?

Tags: perl, templates, catalyst

Is there a way to disabling a `WRAPPER` that was set in  [new(\%config)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template.pm), through either the template, or a temporary override with `parse()`? I want to have a single default `WRAPPER` (that I'll use for 99.9% of my templates), but exclude a few.

I'm doing this all through `Catalyst::View::TT` just like the example in the [configuration synopsis](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/Catalyst-View-TT-0.32/lib/Catalyst/View/TT.pm#CONFIGURATION), except I don't want the `WRAPPER` to apply to all of my templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit the wrapper, to include a conditional like:

```
[% IF no_wrapper OR template.no_wrapper %] [% content %] [% ELSE %]
  top;
    [% content %]
  bottom;
[% END %]
```

This allows me to disable the wrapper either (1) inside of template, or (2) from the stash.

1. `[%- META no_wrapper = 1 -%]`
2. `$c->stash->{no_wrapper} = 1`

`META var ...;` is a directive that makes `var` accessible through the `template` hash as `template.var`

source: http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/gettingstarted/howtos/template_wrappers

Comment: Here is the boiler plate XHTML 1.1 wrapper using this method: http://github.com/EvanCarroll/Craiglickr/blob/master/root/wrapper.tt

Answer (score 4):

Define exceptions in `site/wrapper` itself, and btw there are exceptions defined there already.

```
[% IF template.name.match('\.(css|js|txt)');
     debug("Passing page through as text: $template.name");
     content;
   ELSE;
     debug("Applying HTML page layout wrappers to $template.name\n");
     content WRAPPER site/html + site/layout;
   END;
-%]
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the same problem, and created a more generalized solution that allows for dynamic switching of layouts, or to have no layout at all.  See here:

[More than one layout/wrapper with Dancer and Template::Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198270/more-than-one-layout-wrapper-with-dancer-and-templatetoolkit/18553672#18553672)