# More than one layout/wrapper with Dancer and Template::Toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

I followed this recipe to disable Dancer's "layout" and re-enable TT's "WRAPPER":

[How to make a page-specific title in Dancer templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970625/how-to-make-a-page-specific-title-in-dancer-templates)

which appears to be necessary to change tokens within the layout/wrapper at the route level.  Briefly, the linked recipe requires specifying a single layout/wrapper in the config.yml file.

The recipe works great when using one layout/wrapper, but how do I go about changing (or disabling) the template layout/wrapper at the route level?

Since Dancer's native layout is disabled, this does not work:

```
 template('mytemplate', { ... }, { layout => 'some_other_layout' });   # NO GOOD
```

Also, I tried changing the config prior to rendering template, but that doesn't appear to work either:

```
 # ALSO NO GOOD
 config->{'engines'}->{'template_toolkit'}->{'WRAPPER'} = 'some_other_layout';
 return template('mytemplate', { ... });
```

And I also tried using the Dancer set/setting, but also no good:

```
 # ALSO NO GOOD
 my $engines = setting('engines');
 $engines->{'template_toolkit'}->{'WRAPPER'} = 'some_other_layout';
 set engines => $engines;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Thanks to Yanick and to the link referenced in my other answer (Kludgy Workaround #2) for the inspiration.  Here's the recipe:

1. Create a single wrapper file for use in your entire project, and make it:

   ```
   <% IF layout %>
   <% INCLUDE "$layout" %>
   <% ELSE %>
   <% content %>
   <% END %>
   ```
2. Within your route:

   ```
   return template('mytemplate', {
     layout => 'layouts/some_layout.tt',
     param1 => data1,
     param2 => data2,
     ...
     });
   ```

And bingo, you're done.  Leave out the layout parameter, and will get no layout at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no TT expert, but it seems that once WRAPPER is set for the TemplateToolkit object, it can't be changed.

If that's the case, here's a slightly devious workaround.

1. Set the layout to be, say, 'base.tt'.
2. make that layout to be:

   print $context->process( $stash->get('wrapper'), { 
       content =>  $context->process( $stash->get( 'template.name' ) )
     });
3. and then in your route:

   get '/' => sub {
       template 'index', {
           wrapper => 'layouts/main.tt'
       };
   };

Tadah!

This being said, if you are using Dancer's native layouts, the tokens you're passing to `template` *should* make it to the wrapper code.

Comment: Hi Yanick, 1st & foremost, thanks for your devious :) answer. I'm unclear how to do step #2; am I to include the perl code you suggested in an html'ish layout somehow?  Also I'm assuming that in step #1 I'm setting WRAPPER to 'base.tt'?

Comment: The code in step #2 is meant to be the content of base.tt, and to be surrounde dby [%PERL%] ... [%END%]. But it's the same thing, in spirit, than the accepted solution you wrote below. Your solution is a little nicer too, as it stays in pure TT space, and doesn't resort to perl code. Well done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two incredibly kludgy workarounds (please don't hate me):

**Kludgy Workaround #1**

```
set template => 'simple';
my $html = template('mytemplate', {}, { layout => 'some_other_layout' });
set template => 'template_toolkit';
return $html;
```

Basically, we temporarily switch out template_toolkit for Dancer's 'simple' template renderer.

**Kludgy Workaround #2**

Give up and keep the WRAPPER, but add conditionals so that it gets itself out of the way as described in this post:

[How can I override WRAPPER in a Template Toolkit template file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299561/how-can-i-override-wrapper-in-a-template-toolkit-template-file)